# React video app not working fine on ios while working on android and windows

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My react web video app should work as below;
When the video is running, it should be full screen.
Then When the video ends, the quiz is shown in full screen.
It works fine with all browsers in android and windows.

However, on iOS, the quiz does not appear in full screen after the video ends. When I exit full screen, then quiz appears.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const handleFullscreenChange = () => {
      data.forEach((_, index) => {
        const mainVideo = mainVideoRef.current[index];
  
        if (
          document.fullscreenElement ||
          document.webkitFullscreenElement ||
          document.mozFullScreenElement ||
          document.msFullscreenElement
        ) {
          // Handle fullscreen          
          setVideoStates((prevState) => {
            const newState = [...prevState];
            newState[index] = true;
            return newState;
          });

        // Check if the video has ended
        if (mainVideo.ended) {
          // Show quiz when video is in fullscreen and has ended
          setShowQuiz(true);
        } else {
          setShowQuiz(false);
        }

        } else {
          // Handle exiting fullscreen
          setVideoStates((prevState) => {
            const newState = [...prevState];
            newState[index] = false;
            return newState;
          });
          mainVideo.pause();
          setShowQuiz(false);
          setShowMessage(false);
        }
      });
    };
  
    const handleVideoEndedWrapper = (index) => {
      handleVideoEnded(index);
    };
  
    data.forEach((_, index) => {
      const video = mainVideoRef.current[index];
      video.addEventListener('ended', () => handleVideoEndedWrapper(index));
    });
  
    document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', handleFullscreenChange);
  
    return () => {
      data.forEach((_, index) => {
        const video = mainVideoRef.current[index];
        if (video) {
          video.removeEventListener('ended', () => handleVideoEndedWrapper(index));
        }
      });


      document.removeEventListener('fullscreenchange', handleFullscreenChange);
    };
  }, [data, videoStates, handleVideoEnded]);
```

````
const handleVideoEnded = async (index, videoId) => {
    const videoIdlll = data[index].video_id;
    console.log("handleVideoEnded runs ")    
    getRandomQuestion(data[index].questions)
    async function someAsyncFunction(userId, videoIdlll) {
      const earnPointsForVideoArray = await getUserEarnedPointsForVideo(userId);
      if (earnPointsForVideoArray.includes(videoIdlll)) {
                    return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
    setIsPlaying(false);
    if (user) {
      if (remainingVideoPoints[index] < 1) {
        setExpiredVideoIndex(index);
        setShowQuiz(false); // Do not show quiz for videos with expired points
        setShowNoVideoPoint(true);
      } else if (await someAsyncFunction(user.uid, videoIdlll)) {

        setShowMessage(true);
        console.log(" setShowMessage(true); runs")

      }```
I added console.log for "handleVideoEnded" function.
console.log("handleVideoEnded runs ") -- This runs on both ios and android and windows browsers
console.log(" setShowMessage(true); runs") -- This runs only on android and windows browsers. Not run on iphone.
so when the video ends, quiz is not shown in the full screen on iphone
````

Comment: Have you checked that the `ended` event is called at all? iOS browsers are a bit notorious for handling videos differently to desktop browsers (sometimes better, sometimes worse)

Comment: Yes, I added console.log, Console.log worked on ios